# UISlider in Dynamic UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I am creating an app in where I need to add a bunch of sliders in a Dynamic UITableView. I added the slider like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc]init];
    //ALL OTHER CODE
    [cell addSubview:slider];
    return cell;
}
```

Now the slider is added to the UITableView but the if I changed the value of the first slider another slider changes with it.I know this is something to do with dequeing the cell but how do I fix it?

**EDIT:**

I tried @daveMack answer like this:

**CustomCell.m:**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.checkBox = [[M13Checkbox alloc]initWithTitle:@"Checkbox!"];
        self.checkBox.checkAlignment = M13CheckboxAlignmentLeft;
        [self addSubview:self.checkBox];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Cell For Row At Index Path:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CheckboxCell *cell;

    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CheckboxCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        return cell;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no, no! I would not suggest you add views like that to your `UITableViewCell`. Funky stuff can happen as you have experienced yourself because of the dequeueing process.

I suggest you do the following:

1. Create a custom table view cell with its appropriate `.h`, `.m` file and `.xib` file
2. In your custom cell you can add WHATEVER views you like and however many views that you like.
3. Make sure you create a `property` of type `UIScrollView` in your `.h` file and link it to the interface builder to your custom cell's slider, call the property `slider`.
4. Now in your main view controller where you are creating your table, make sure you have an `NSMutableArray` and name it something like `sliderValuesArray` that can store all your slider values for each cell. You want to make sure that the number of cells is equal to the number of elements in your `sliderValuesArray`.
5. Then you can do something like this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method:

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method do something like this:

```
myCustomCell.slider.maximumValue = 100;
myCustomCell.slider.minimumValue = 1;
myCustomCell.slider.continuous = TRUE;
//set a method which will get called when a slider in a cell changes value
[myCustomCell.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//Keep a reference to each slider by assigning a tag so that we can determine 
//which slider is being changed
myCustomCell.slider.tag = indexPath.row;

//Grab the value from the sliderValuesArray and set the slider knob to that position
myCustomCell.slider.value = [[sliderValuesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];
```

Now in your  `sliderChanged` method you can do this:

```
-(void)sliderChanged:(UISlider)sender{
    //Grab the slider value, it needs to be converted to an NSNumber so that we can
    //store it successfully as an object in our sliderValuesArray
    NSNumber sliderValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.value];
    //This is how we determine which position in our slidersArray we want to update,
    //Based on the tag we set our slider view on initialisation in our cellForRowAtIndexPath
    int cellPosition = sender.tag;

    //Use the cellPosition to update the correct number in our sliderValuesArray
    //with the sliderValue retrieved from the slider that the user is sliding
    [sliderValuesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:cellPosition withObject:sliderValue];
}
```

Comment: Great @AbdullahShafique :)

Comment: Since cells are re-usable, is there a possibility that the target and action for the slider are added everytime `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue awhile back. The solution I came up with was to subclass UITableViewCell. Then I added the slider in the init method of the subclass and exposed it via a property.

Now, when you want to change the value of JUST ONE slider, you would do something like:

```
[cell slider]setValue:(someValue)];
```

Comment: This works great but when I scroll done and then come back up it loses its value.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique Yeah dude look at my answer bro. You'll see how to correct it.